# Move secure store db using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am curious if there's a way to move the secure store db to another db using powershell.

- move it to a different server

Thanks

Comment: What u want, move secure store db to different server or create new db for secure store service?

Comment: move it to a different server if possible...if not we'll need to create a new db for secure store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported commands to move the Secure Store DB from one Server to others. You have to do it manually. But if you want, you can create a new database for Secure Store Database.

**To create New Database**

- You can use the Set-SPSecureStoreServiceApplication command.To create a new db for the Secure Store Service.
- Another approach is to delete the current Secure Store Service and then recreate it using powershell.[Follow this for creation new SS application](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/a88f7b6e-9c9e-475f-afd1-c68c4ef3cc4a) or [this](http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-how-to-configure-secure.html)

Or you can do it as MSFT recomend.

- Stop the service application
- Detach the database from SQL Server
- Move database files to a new location
- Attach the database to a new instance of SQL Server
- Point the service application to a moved database

[here is the MSFT tech net Article.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729798.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)